# Saving chrome timeline data via javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Starting and stopping the dev tools timeline is easy:

```
console.timeline("timeline1");
console.timelineEnd();
```

I am looking for a way to extract the data from a timeline and post it to a server.  Or trigger the browsers 'save timeline data'.  I want to collect timeline data from peoples machines while they test a web application.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: A very good question! Any update on this, did you figure anything out?

Comment: 'console.timeline' is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

This data might be available in an extension, but unfortunately it's not available in standard Javascript. Also, as mentioned before "timeline" is now deprecated, instead you should use console.time() or console.timeEnd().