# Profiling Javascript performance using API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, performance-testing, profiler

Hey I have been exploring the google-chrome debugging tools and profiling tools. Its truly amazing. One useful stuff I encountered is I get the call tree of the executions and their time taken (both self time and total children time count) in a full tree structure.

So I would like to know if we can get the call-tree with their timings in a tree structure using some JS API. I can use this tree timings to benchmark the different versions of my code and various other cool stuffs could be done, if I can automate.

I couldnot find much useful stuff over net. Can you give me some direction to this? Thanks in advance.

Let me know in comments if some parts are unclear in the question.I will rephrase myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to benchmark different versions of your app, you can easily achieve this in Profiles in Chrome DevTools. You can record and save them to your computer, and then load them again anytime in the future. It's not just for the current session.

For example, you record your profile for Version 1. A few days later you load up your app in Chrome, record the new Profile and then import the old one and compare the charts or the tree view.

You could even open the saved files on your computer, which are stored in JSON format. You have all the data you need in there to play with. You can run a server to parse that data and extract the relevant information into a format you like. The amount of data can be huge and slow to handle though.

[image: Profiles]

## Update regarding comment:

Both `console.timeline` and `console.timelineEnd` were deprecated and replaced with `console.time` and `console.timeEnd`. However, there are no return values to store, so you can't do anything with the results in JavaScript. However, you can use [window.performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance):

```
var start = window.performance.now();
// your function
var end = window.performance.now();
var timeSpent = (end - start);
var stack = new Error().stack; // get call stack
```

You could then do what you like with the results.
If you want to time a function from a 3rd party, you could override it and `apply` the original function in between:

```
var oldFunc = myFunc;

myFunc = function() {
    var start = window.performance.now();
    var returnVal = oldFunc.apply(this, arguments);
    var end = window.performance.now();
    var timeSpent = (end - start);
    var stack = new Error().stack; // get call stack
    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Gideon, g8 you just solved 50% of my problem. Do you have any leads on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613911/saving-chrome-timeline-data-via-javascript-api.
If we can do this, its over. Any idea bro?

Comment: @Ayan See my updated answer. I hope it helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [console.profile()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/profile) and [console.profileEnd()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/profileEnd) to start and stop recording a profile.  After it runs, you can see the result in the Profiles tab of the developer tools.

Comment: Yeah tats the manual inspection @Daniel. I want to do it programatically.
Say I have a library called ABC.

I profiled it using console.profile. Save the profiling results in a tree structure say in tree1.
I make some changes to the ABC codes.
I re-profiled it. Again stroring the structure in say tree2.

Now programatically I compare two structures and say hey due to the changes made, this and this function now takes these much time more or less.

A fully automated profiling.. Is that doable, sir?